# How can I get PID(s) of a running Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, linux, jupyter-notebook, process, fenics

I have run several (`n`) Jupyter notebooks in parallel.  As they use FEniCS, each has spawned a number (much more than `m - 1`) of threads (PIDs) which can occupy all available cores (`m`).  Now I have much more than `m * n` threads (of at least `n` processes) which compete for resources (cores, RAM etc.).  That significantly damps their performance.

As I need results of some of the notebooks more urgently the of the others, I would like to set priorities of their PIDs accordingly (`renice` them).  Sadly I have no idea which PIDs belongs to which notebook.  How can I verify that without interrupting the notebooks?

I know I can stop all my notebooks but one (the least important), use `htop` to `renice` the processes which still use CPU, then run the other notebooks one by one and repeat the procedure.  But is there a way to do it while all the notebooks are running?

Comment: @anarchy Not exactly, but that led me in the right direction.